# Why is LiveData onChanged called before data change is made?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

**Context**

Using `MutableLiveData` to hold a value. `Button` click should increment the value.

**Problem**

`MutableLiveData`'s `Observer.onChanged()` appears to be called before `MutableLiveData.setValue()` is used to change the value.

For example, before `Button` click, `onChanged` log happens after initial value is set (`onChanged` nanoseconds is greater than new value nanoseconds) . However, after `Button` click, `onChanged` log happens before new value is set (`onChanged` nanoseconds is less than new value nanoseconds). Why does this happen?:

Before `Button` click (`onChanged` log expectedly happens after setting initial val):

```
09-06 20:30:47.877 com.example.android.test D/TAG: initial set val ns 102107899222617
    initial get val ns 102107899367096
09-06 20:30:47.882 com.example.android.test D/TAG: onChanged integer 0 ns 102107903996992
```

After Button click (`onChanged` log *unexpectedly* happens before setting new val):

```
09-06 20:30:55.372 com.example.android.test D/TAG: onChanged integer 1 ns 102115394178238
09-06 20:30:55.373 com.example.android.test D/TAG: onClick set new val 1 ns 102115394446415
```

**Code**

```
final MutableLiveData<Integer> val = new MutableLiveData<>();
val.setValue(0); // triggers onChanged
Log.d(TAG, "initial set val ns " + System.nanoTime());

tv.setText("" + val.getValue());
Log.d(TAG, "initial get val ns " + System.nanoTime());

val.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
        // onChanged happens after initial setValue but before setValue with new value
        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged integer " + integer + " ns " + System.nanoTime());
        tv.setText("" + integer);
    }
});

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // setting new value (triggers onChanged but 
        // onChanged happens before setting new value via setValue)
        int newVal = val.getValue() + 1;
        val.setValue(newVal);
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick set new val " + newVal + " ns " + System.nanoTime());
    }
});
```

Comment: call `Log.d(TAG, "onClick set new val " + newVal + " ns " + System.nanoTime());` before calling `val.setValue(newVal);`

Comment: @pskink Makes sense, just wanted to clarify that `onChanged` was happening after `setValue`, thanks

Comment: otherwise you would discover a time machine when the light bulb goes off even before you switch it off ;-)

Comment: @pskink nice analogy ;) also, to close this question, should I add the edit as the answer, just leave it, or does it not need an accepted answer?

Comment: you can write a self answer

Comment: if it helps others avoid this problem, sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @pskink pointed out, the problem was placement of the log for setting new value, logging before and after the `MutableLiveValue.setValue()` made it clear:

Add before and after logs:

```
final MutableLiveData<Integer> val = new MutableLiveData<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setValue before");
        super.setValue(value);
        Log.d(TAG, "setValue after");
    }
};
```

After `Button` click (`onChanged` log expectedly happens after `setValue`):

```
09-06 20:52:02.869 com.example.android.test D/TAG: onClick: before set new val
    setValue before
09-06 20:52:02.870 com.example.android.test D/TAG: onChanged integer 1 ns 103382891472200
    setValue after
    onClick after set new val 1 ns 103382891671576
```

**Edit**

The reason logging after `setValue` happened after `onChanged` is because `onChanged` is called at some point in `setValue`.